# How do I view Obj-C subclass variables from Swift in the Xcode debugger?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode10

I've got a mixed Obj-C / Swift project. Whenever I hit a breakpoint in a Swift class, the Obj-C object variables view just shows values for parent classes, but not the subclass itself.

For instance, if I have the following Obj-C class:

```
@interface CameraPlayerCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) Camera* camera;
@end
```

When I hit a breakpoint in my Swift CollectionViewController implementation, the Xcode debugger values view shows:

[image: XcodeDebuggerVariablesView]

Searched for this for about an hour, but apparently I don't know how to ask Google what I'm looking for (or they're just being Google & showing me what they *think* I want rather than what I actually want...)

I *know* there is a way to add an expression to the Variables View so that it will show the member variables for `CameraPlayerCell`. I've read an article *somewhere* and have done this before, but for the life of me I cannot remember how to do it.

Comment: “When I hit a breakpoint”. But show us that breakpoint. If you have not cast the cell down, there is no reason to see it as a subclass.

Comment: It has been cast down. Sorry, I thought that would be clear with the screenshot : `cell = (CameraPlayerCell)`. Variables View shows it as whatever type it's currently being interpreted as.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `frame variable`?

[From Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/lldb-guide/chapters/C5-Examining-The-Call-Stack.html):
"*You use the frame variable (f v) command to get a list of all the variables in the stack frame.*"

> Example:

[image: frame variable]

Comment: Yeah, I can definitely get access via LLDB no problem. I just wanted to get it showing up in the Variables View.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the value:

```
po (CameraPlayerCell *)cell
```

Then you can access the subclass properties:

```
po ((CameraPlayerCell *) cell).camera
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Getting access in LLDB is no problem. I just wanted it to work in the Variables View so I don't have to type as much.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine on my machine. Keep in mind that an Objective-C property is merely a shorthand for accessor methods for an ivar; it is the ivar that will appear in the variables list. (I assume that yours is automatically synthesized.)

[image]

Comment: That's interesting... I wonder if there's something else going on here then.

Comment: Well, even though I asked, you didn't provide a reproducible test case, so there's no way I can guess what the difference might be.